# Python if element from list exists in file append with success %

Tags: python, file

So my goal here is to go through a lot of files in a folder searching for certain string values contained in a list and then append a local list with the files that contain those strings, as well as a value of how many of those string values are in said file. **My problem** seems to be that the "any" function doesn't work with "key"? Is there another function I should be using or a work around to this?

Something like this:

```
import os
success = []
keywords = ["the", "of", "from", "north", "south", "east", "west", "to", "county", "have", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six","seven", "eight", "nine"]
total = len(keywords)
folder = ("C:Folder//Path")
folder_paths = [os.path.join(folder, file) for file in os.listdir(folder)]
for f in folder_paths:
    wins= 0
    for key in keywords in f:
        wins+=1
    confidence = Str(wins/total) + "%"
    if confidence>=1:
        success.append(str(f) + confidence)

print(success)
```

Comment: You haven't stated any problem.  Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: Edited with the problem I'm having. You won't be able to copy the code into a file and run it without a manual edit to a file path on your computer, as the setting for the problem alludes to.

Comment: Even with that edit, this code doesn't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a refactoring with a fix.

`filter(lambda key: key in f, keywords)` returns a list of the `keywords` which are found in `f`, and its `len` indicates how many there are.

This could perhaps be rephrased to use `all()` (not `any()` which terminates as soon as it finds one match) but it seems like a convoluted way to do things.

This still assumes that you are looking for the strings in the file *names,* not the contents of the files you are looping over.

Other changes:

- `total` was trivial enough that I just inlined it; the Python optimizer will probably take care of calculating it just once for us anyway.
- `folder_paths` was only used once, so inlined it
- *Forward* slashes don't have to be doubled. You seemed to lack a slash after `C:` so added that.
- `f` is already a string, so `str(f)` is redundant
- `Str()` should apparently be `str()`
- `confidence` has to be a number so that you can compare whether it's bigger than 1.

```py
import os

success = []
keywords = ["the", "of", "from", "north", "south", "east", "west", "to", "county", "have", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six","seven", "eight", "nine"]
folder = ("C:/Folder/Path")
for f in [os.path.join(folder, file) for file in os.listdir(folder)]:
    wins = len(list(filter(lambda key: key in f, keywords)))
    confidence = wins/len(keywords)
    if confidence >= 1:
        success.append(f + str(confidence) + "%")

print(success)
```

A better design would probably be to create a function which returns a dictionary of `f: wins/len(keywords)` and have the caller format that into a human-readable form for printing.

Comment: This looks like it would be closest to what I need thank you! I do get an error when I attempt to run this however. "object of type 'filter' has no len()'. Any ideas? Cursory google research of the error didn't find me what I needed unfortunately ;-;

Comment: Oh sorry, `filter` in Python 3 is a generator. I'll update the code.

Comment: Had to make a slight change to your code but this was incredibly helpful!

Made the last section "if wins >= 1" since we made confidence a str and we can't get a boolean value out of that. Wins accomplishes the same thing though. 

You are a scholar and a saint, thank you so much!

Comment: I'd vote this up but I'm new and I think the admin didn't like my question so it got voted down? Should I ever get 15 reputation I'll come back and give you your karmatic dividends.

Comment: There is no "the admin" and the moderators have exactly the same voting rights as the rest of us. Somebody with at least 50 rep didn't like your question; such things happen (and I agree that you should probably review [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) before posting again). But thanks (-: The accept already got me +15 so I'm good.

Comment: Updated the code to make `confidence` a number. Thanks for noting this problem. (Perhaps the number you want to compare is actually `wins`, though. The value of `confidence` will be less than 1 if there were fewer wins than there are keywords.)

Answer (score 0):

you can try with nltk and these are proven libraries. Below is the code that can help you.

```
# import nltk and pandas
import nltk
import pandas as pd
my_files=['my_random.txt','my_random.txt'] # my files
```

```
my_keyword=['solutions','Solar']
df_list=[] # for storing dataframe of each file
for each_file in my_files:
    with open(each_file,"r") as f_r:
        file_content=f_r.read()
    
    tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(file_content)
    valid_tokens=[each_t for each_t in tokens if each_t in my_keyword] # words which are in keyword
    fd = nltk.FreqDist(valid_tokens) # dict word:frequency
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(fd, orient='index')
    df_list.append(df) # now df_list will have all word frequencies
```

In df_list is a list contains dataframe for each file.
you can move them to result if needed.

```
result=df_list[0]
for each_df in df_list[1:]:
    result=result+each_df
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OzIq.png)